# How to adjust the tabs in my Shiny app to appear when hovering instead of creating new rows of tabs?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

The code for my application is:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      body, .gt_table {
        font-family: system-ui, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji';
      }
      .title-wrapper {
        background-color: #6b4c2d;
        padding: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }
      .title-wrapper h1, .person-ratings {
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: system-ui, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji';
        font-weight: normal;
      }
      .title-line1, .title-line2, .person-line {
        border: none;
        height: 7px;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .title-line1 {
        background-color: #e2eff5;
      }
      .title-line2 {
        background-color: #b8d8e7;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .person-person {
        background-color: #6b4c2d;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 7.5px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 16.5px;
        margin-top: 5px;
      }
      .person-line {
        background-color: #b8d8e7;
      }
      .nav-tabs {
        border-bottom: none !important;
      }
      .nav-tabs > li.active > a {
        background-color: #b8d8e7 !important;
        color: white !important;
        font-weight: normal !important;
      }
      .nav-tabs > li > a {
        background-color: white !important;
        color: #6b4c2d !important;
      }
    "))
  ),
  div(class = "title-wrapper",
      HTML("<h1>Title</h1>")
  ),
  tags$hr(class = "title-line1"),
  tags$hr(class = "title-line2"),
    tabPanel("Person",
             fluidRow(
               column(width = 4, align = "center", offset = 4,
                      selectInput("person", "Choose a person:", choices = unique(df$name))
               )
             ),
             fluidRow(
               column(width = 8, offset = 2,
                      h3("--------", class = "person-person"),
                      hr(class = "person-line"),
                      uiOutput("person_tbl")
               ),
               column(width = 8, offset = 2,
                      plotOutput("person_plot")
               )
             )
             )
)
```

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # server code here ---------
}
```

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Basically, my problem is adjusting the tabs in my application. Currently, I only have the "Person" tab, but I want to implement a new tab with subtabs. I have fooled around with creating the new tabs, which is the easy part, but I want the navigation to be more user friendly. Just adding the tabs gives you the generic click on a tab then another row of subtabs pop up and it is not very pleasing to the eye. I want to be able to hover over the new tab, call it "New Tab" and be able to see all of the subtabs, call them "Sub 1" and "Sub 2".

Comment: I don't understand your desired output. What about [accordions](https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/articles/dashboards/index.html#accordions) in bslib?

Comment: What about a `navbarMenu`?